# initial addround key process in AES

Tags: aes

how sub key generated in initial round process.What is the process involved in generation of key in addround step in initial stage.

how we are getting 
[k0,k4,k8,k12

k1,k5,k9,k13

k2,k6,k10,k14

k3,k7,k11,k15]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_key_schedule

Comment: Welcome to crypto-SE. There are [guidelines](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for writing good questions, and it is useful for everyone to note what research you have done already.